# Interactions with Remix Variation Modal in Midjourney Discord using Python and Discum

Tags: discord.py, discum

I am using Discum to interact with Midjourney in Discord and I am able to interact with V1,V2,V3,V4 buttons through discum. However, I am not able to figure out how to pass input to the Remix prompt (Modal).

Remix Prompt

[Remix Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdS36.png)

Reference Image

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mssLA.jpg)

If the Discum solution is not present for now, can we do it through the Discord API?

I've Toggled on the remix using /prefer remix. The following code triggers the Variation.

```
url = self.discord + "interactions"
            nonce = calculateNonce("now")

            component_type = message.components[1]["components"][image_no - 1]

            payload = {
                "type": 3,
                "application_id": CONFIG.APPLICATION_ID,
                "guild_id": CONFIG.GUILD_ID,
                "channel_id": CONFIG.CHANNEL_ID,
                "data": {
                    "component_type": component_type["type"],
                    "custom_id": component_type["custom_id"]
                },
                "nonce": nonce,
                "message_flags": 0,
                "message_id": message.message_id,
                "session_id": "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(32))
            }

            fields = {"payload_json": (None, json.dumps(payload))}
            randomstr = ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, 16))
            body = MultipartEncoder(fields=fields, boundary='----WebKitFormBoundary' + randomstr)
            headerMods = {"update": {"Content-Type": body.content_type}}

            return Wrapper.sendRequest(self.s, 'post', url, body, headerModifications=headerMods, log=self.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise not to spend too much time to investigate Discord+Midjourney There are tonns of services providing pure free API to your Discord+MJ account. You can try [userapi.ai](https://userapi.ai) (free), goapi, tnl, etc...